# Disabling action on the promise failure using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having the problem on disabling action on the promise rejection

Here is my code:

```
if (actions.length) {
   const action = actions.shift();
   action.rule(context).then(function () {
     this.set('validAction', action);
     this.set('disabledAction', null);
   }.bind(this), testAction);
} else {
   this.set('disabledAction', defaultIcon);
   this.set('validAction', null);
}
```

the last else block should execute on the "not condition" of the `promise(action.rule(context))`
How to code it?

Comment: Add the _last else block_ to `testAction` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to bind `this` to the promise then callback if you use arrow functions, and secondly you should do the fail logic in a `catch`.

Here's how I would write this:

```
if (actions.length) {
   const action = actions.shift();
   action
    .rule(context)
    .then( () =>  {
      this.set('validAction', action);
      this.set('disabledAction', null);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.set('disabledAction', defaultIcon);
      this.set('validAction', null);
    });
}
```

You could also use `async/await`, but given the code sample I think this might be a bit out of your scope, something like so:

```
async function verifyRule(actions) {
  if (actions.length) {
    const action = actions.shift();
    const hasRule = await action.rule(context);

    if(hasRule) {
      this.set('validAction', action);
      this.set('disabledAction', null);
    } else {
      this.set('disabledAction', defaultIcon);
      this.set('validAction', null);
    }
  }
}
```